# How to match every thing except some character ? regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have these two strings:

s2 = ***start*** bla bla bla `word1` bla bla bla  `word1` **value1** `word1` bla bla bla

s1= ***start*** bla bla bla `word1` bla bla bla  `word1` bla bla bla `word1` **value1**

I want to check if `s` has the value1, but it should be after the the second`word1`.
so s1 should return the value1, but s2 should return None because value1 come after the third word1.

I tried this:

```
re.search('start(.*?word1){2}\s+(value1)')
```

the problem that my search return value1 for the s1 and s2 ? because `.` include every thing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion like below. The below regex would capture the string `value1` only if it's preceded by exactly two `word1` strings from the start .

```
r'start(?:(?:(?!word1).)*word1){2}(?:(?!word1).)*?(value1)'
```

`(?:(?!word1).)*` would match any character but not of `word1` zero or more times. That is before matching a single character, regex engine would check for the character is not `w` followed by `ord1`. If there isn't, then only the regex engine would match the following character. This check would happen before matching each and every character. It would stops matching once it saw `word1` string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zP9fK5/1)

```
>>> import re
>>> s2 = "start bla bla bla word1 bla bla bla word1 value1 word1 bla bla bla"
>>> s1= "start bla bla bla word1 bla bla bla word1 bla bla bla word1 value1"
>>> re.search(r'start(?:(?:(?!word1).)*word1){2}(?:(?!word1).)*?(value1)', s2)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f0bb60e9558>
>>> re.search(r'start(?:(?:(?!word1).)*word1){2}(?:(?!word1).)*?(value1)', s2).group(1)
'value1'
>>> re.search(r'start(?:(?:(?!word1).)*word1){2}(?:(?!word1).)*?(value1)', s1)
>>>
```

Comment: wow you are clever ! now I am trying to understand your expression !

Comment: is there a difference between    (?:.(?!word1))*     and     (?:(?!word1).)*

Comment: yep, there is a difference.

Comment: what's the difference ?

Comment: `(?:.(?!word1))*` matches any character but not the one which is followed by the string `word1`.That is, it checks the string or character following the character in which we are going to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function , that use `re.findall` and positive [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in regex :

```
>>> def find(val,s):
...  if re.findall(r'(?<=word1 )\w+',s)[1]==val:
...    return val
...  else :
...    return None
... 
>>> print find('value1',s1)
None
>>> print find('value1',s2)
value1
```

Comment: what (?<=word1) mean ?

Comment: @david its positive lookbehind in regex , i add the link in answer. It tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string,and match every thing in front of `()` ,( here `(?<=word1 )`) and it match every `\w+` that came after `word1`